# How to add static text in map using Plotly Choropleth Python

Tags: python, plot, plotly, geojson, choropleth

I am plotting a map using plotly express and geojson file.I want to show static values on the individual district. Currently those values are visible on hover, but I want the values to be seen all the time even without hovering on it.

This is my code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio

x = json.load(open("./odisha_disticts.geojson","r"))

user_data = []
for i in range(len(x['features'])):
    d = x['features'][i]['properties']
    d['Females'] = np.random.randint(0,100,1)[0]
    user_data.append(d)
df = pd.DataFrame(user_data)

df.head()
    ID_2    NAME_2  Females
0   16084   Angul   19
1   16085   Baleshwar   45
2   16086   Baragarh    52
3   16087   Bhadrak     81
4   16088   Bolangir    49

fig = px.choropleth(
    df,
    locations="ID_2",
    featureidkey="properties.ID_2",
    geojson=x,
    color="Females"
)
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)

px.scatter_geo(
    df,
    geojson=x,
    featureidkey="properties.NAME_2",
    locations="District",
    text = df["District"]
)

fig.show()
```

The link to required files is [HERE](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10do9-weVkqci8MJIgYmF-fRbSC1aqzxt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To annotate on a map, use a `graph_object` to `go.Choroplethmapbox` with `go.Scattermapbox` with textmode. As a preparation before creating the graph, we need the latitude and longitude for the annotation, so we use geopandas to read the geojson file and find the center of geometry. A warning is displayed at this point because the loaded geometry uses an inappropriate geodetic system to calculate the center. If you have a latitude and longitude you wish to use for your annotations use it. There are two caveats in creating the map: first, you will need the free Mapbox API token. Get it [here](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-layers/#mapbox-maps-vs-geo-maps). second, in go.Scattemapbox(), the mode is text + marker, but if you use text only, an error will occur. The reason is unknown.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# read your data 
data = pd.read_csv('./data.csv', index_col=0)
# read geojson
x = json.load(open("./odisha_disticts.geojson","r"))

gdf = gpd.read_file('./odisha_disticts.geojson')

gdf['centroid'] = gdf['geometry'].centroid
gdf['lon'] = gdf['centroid'].map(lambda p:p.x)
gdf['lat'] = gdf['centroid'].map(lambda p:p.y)
gdf.head()
    ID_2    NAME_2  geometry    centroid    lon     lat
0   16084   Angul   POLYGON ((85.38891 21.17916, 85.31440 21.15510...   POINT (84.90419 20.98316)   84.904186   20.983160
1   16085   Baleshwar   POLYGON ((87.43902 21.76406, 87.47124 21.70760...   POINT (86.90547 21.48738)   86.905470   21.487376
2   16086   Baragarh    POLYGON ((83.79293 21.56323, 83.84026 21.52344...   POINT (83.34884 21.22068)   83.348838   21.220683
3   16087   Bhadrak     POLYGON ((86.82882 21.20137, 86.82379 21.13752...   POINT (86.61598 20.97818)   86.615981   20.978183
4   16088   Bolangir    POLYGON ((83.45259 21.05145, 83.44352 21.01535...   POINT (83.16839 20.58812)   83.168393   20.588121

import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

mapbox_token = open("mapbox_api_key.txt").read()

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(lat=gdf['lat'],
                               lon=gdf['lon'],
                               mode='text+markers',
                               textposition='top center',
                               text = [str(x) for x in data["District"]],
                               textfont=dict(color='blue')
))

fig.add_trace(go.Choroplethmapbox(geojson=x,
                                  locations=data['id'],
                                  z=data['Females'],
                                  featureidkey="properties.ID_2",
                                  colorscale='Reds',
                                  zmin=0,
                                  zmax=data['Females'].max(),
                                  marker_opacity=0.8,
                                  marker_line_width=0
                                 )
             )

fig.update_layout(height=600,
                  mapbox=dict(
                      center={"lat": gdf['lat'].mean(), "lon": gdf['lon'].mean()},
                      accesstoken=mapbox_token,
                      zoom=5.5,
                      style="light"
))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is it necessary to use mapbox api ??
As i have already used a geojson file to locate the area....

Comment: API token (free) is required since mapbox will be used. This code stores the API token locally in a text file and then reads and specifies it. `mapbox_token = open("mapbox_api_key.txt").read()`

Comment: I don't actually have a card to open the account..

Comment: No credit card should be required. go to mapbox and press sign up. Enter your username, email, password and agree to the policy. Then select Get Started and you will receive an authentication email to the registered email you just registered. Click on the link in the body of the email to be directed to the mapbox site and register the password you have set. copy the access token from the Dashboad page and save it in your locale.